# @SceneStorage doesn't seem to work on mac

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

## Overview

- Below stated code doesn't work on macOS
- Selection is not retained across launches

## My observation

- When I run on Xcode and stop running in Xcode, then the selection is retained when I run again.
- However if I run on Xcode and then Quit (Command Q) then the selection is not retained.
- The selection is not retained when the app is archived into a separate app.

## Questions

1. Am I missing something?
2. What should I do to retain selection?

## Code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @SceneStorage("selectedIndex") var selectedIndex: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<10, selection: $selectedIndex) { index in
            Text("Cell \(index)")
                .id(index)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From the docs: If the Scene is explicitly destroyed (e.g. the switcher snapshot is destroyed on iPadOS or the window is closed on macOS), the data is also destroyed.

Comment: Maybe you’re looking for AppStorage?

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks a lot!! I had missed the documentation. I could use `AppStorage` (`UserDefaults`), but just wondering if it is a common practice to store selected cell id in `AppStore`(`Userdefaults`)? Is AppStorage the recommended approach for cell selection or any other approach?

Comment: usually I think you'd reach for these kinds of things for user preferences. Sometimes on lightweight or toy apps you can utilize this and it's fine, but for anything more production-y or user data-y I'd use an actual database (sql / CoreData) or write things to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scenestorage

> If the Scene is explicitly destroyed (e.g. the switcher snapshot is destroyed on iPadOS or the window is closed on macOS), the data is also destroyed.

Given the above, `SceneStorage` isn't a good fit for your requirement of persistent-across-launches.

[`AppStorage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/appstorage) may be a better choice, for example.

Answer (score 1):

> However if I run on Xcode and then Quit (Command Q) then the selection is not retained.

It would have appeared so because `SceneStorage` saves the state after a slight delay - so if you quit the app soon after you change a `SceneStorage` value, it will not be restored as expected.

[SwiftUI on the Mac: Build the fundamentals](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10062/)

In my experience, `SceneStorage` does restore values across launches (as long as the windows are not closed prior to quitting). It works as expected with your sample and in Apple's code mentioned here.

Comment: Yeah sometimes user might close the window which causes the value not to be saved. For now I use AppStorage